# downgradeModule doesn't start Angular5 part in hybrid app

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-upgrade, angular5

Angular5 introduced a new way of upgrating app from AngularJS to Angular -
 `downgradeModule`. It should resolve an issue with to eager change detection in this kind of hybrid application. So far, in Angular4 I used `UpgradeModule` successfully, but it caused some performance issue because of change detections. Now I'm trying to use `downgradeModule`. In this approach AngularJS is started first, next downgradeModule starts Angular. In this way AngularJS in running outside of AngularZone, what should calm down change detection.

`main.ts` which is pointed in `.angular-cli.json` as "main"

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import {enableProdMode, StaticProvider} from '@angular/core';
import { downgradeModule } from '@angular/upgrade/static';

enableProdMode();
declare var angular: any;

const bootstrapFn = (extraProviders: StaticProvider[]) => {
    const platformRef = platformBrowserDynamic(extraProviders);
    return platformRef.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
};
const myDowngradedModule = downgradeModule(bootstrapFn);

angular.bootstrap(document.documentElement, [
    'legacyApp',
    myDowngradedModule
]);
```

Now, AngularJS starts well, but Angular **does not**. No error on console, no tips. Just main selector eg. `<my-app>` is not evaluated.
Nothing changed in `app.module.ts` in context of previous working version.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    UpgradeModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([], { initialNavigation: false })
  ],
providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : '/shop/' }],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]    
})
export class AppModule {
  ngDoBootstrap() {}
}
```

I use some draft Angular doc, because the major one doesn't say anything about `downgradeModule`.
https://pr18487-aedf0aa.ngbuilds.io/guide/upgrade-performance

Does anyone know why Angular5 part is not starting?

Only for information purpose, the previous look of `main.ts` with `UpgradeModule` which worked quite well, but change detection.

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(platformRef => {
   const upgrade = platformRef.injector.get(UpgradeModule) as UpgradeModule;
   upgrade.bootstrap(document.documentElement, ['legacyApp']);
   platformRef.injector.get(Router).initialNavigation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

LancerX, have you tried adding AppComponent to the entryComponents in AppModule?

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        BrowserModule,
        UpgradeModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([], { initialNavigation: false })
    ],
    providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : '/shop/' }],
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    entryComponents: [ AppComponent ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]    
})

export class AppModule {
    ngDoBootstrap() {}
}
```

Comment: I didn't try before, but now I do and nothing is changed. I saw your post "Using downgradeModule in conjunction..." and tried to do the same (except of decorateModuleRef which I don't know) and in `main.ts` replace `angular.bootstrap(document.documentElement []....` with `var legacyApp = angular.module('legacyApp', [ downgradedModule, ....`. Now  I have error `Module 'legacyApp' is not available!`

Comment: LancerX, I am using the declarative bootstrap of angular 1.x in the html file... <html ... ng-app="app" ng-strict-di="true" ...>

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of the AoT-Compilation. We had a similar Problem and solved it by deactivating aot.

Also see https://pr18487-aedf0aa.ngbuilds.io/guide/upgrade-performance#using-ahead-of-time-compilation-with-hybrid-apps

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, and it was because I registered the downgraded component with a bad name. I registered it like this:

```
angular.module("myModule").directive("my-component", downgradeComponent({ component: MyComponent}));
```

But it should have been this:

```
angular.module("myModule").directive("myComponent", downgradeComponent({ component: MyComponent}));
```

So the component was never initialized because the name was wrong. And because the downgraded module is lazy-loaded (it isn't loaded until one of the components are loaded), the module was never initialized either. Fixing the directive name fixed the problem.